# Ruby on Rails webhost recommendation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, web-hosting

Can someone recommend a web host that will allow me to use the latest versions both of Ruby and Rails?  I tried Dreamhost but they're running Ruby 1.8.7 which would mean I'd have to rewrite my entire app.  But the most I can afford is around $10/month.

Comment: It's worth noting, too, that Rails will officially quit supporting Ruby 1.8 soon. Rails 4 isn't even compatible with it. Silly Dreamhost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) is your friend.

- Free for a single dyno.
- Lots of addons with free tiers.
- No mucking about in server admin duties.
- Deploy via git.
- Specify your Ruby interpreter and version via Gemfile
- Asset compilation on-push

It's just too easy.

Comment: To clarify `Free for a single dyno.` you can host your site completely free until you need to scale up resources to handle larger volume. Heroku is for sure the best choice.

Comment: Can I use MySQL on Heroku?

Comment: @mikeglaz Yes, along with about a dozen other databases — https://addons.heroku.com/#data-stores — though I would recommend that you at least give PostgreSQL a shot.

Comment: @coreyward I am playing around with Heroku.  I'm a programmer and am new to networks and web hosting.  I am trying to use a custom domain. The Heroku docs brought me to Zeringo DNS.  Is a DNS server the same as a nameserver?  My domain is registered with godaddy and I need to specify nameservers to point to Heroku.  Are these Zeringo DNS servers (i.e. a.ns.zerigo.net) what I need to put into the godaddy nameserver?

Comment: @mikeglaz Essentially, yes. If you want to use Zerigo for your DNS hosting (which is a pretty good option), you would set your “Name Servers” in GoDaddy to `a.ns.zerigo.net` and `b.ns.zerigo.net` (you can go all the way through `e`, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [webfaction](http://www.webfaction.com). Not free, but very cheap, awesome support. Shared hosting, but you get ssh access and close to full control. You can install your own software if needed. It is great if you want more control or want to do more than just a rails site. And it is easier to manage yourself, e.g. when compared to a [linode](http://linode.com) for instance (where you have *complete* control, but have to setup everything yourself).

Comment: WTF! Down-voted? Man, it is just my opinion, I am just using this and I want to share it. I use for wordpress hosting, git hosting (my private repos), redmine and a few silly rails sites I built myself. And I am not smart enough to do a linode myself, so I find webfaction just awesome. Whatever.

Comment: They support ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.1 since february last year! [see here](http://blog.webfaction.com/2012/02/welcoming-rails-3-2-1-and-ruby-1-9-3/).

Answer (score 0):

$10 is a pretty big budget in my opinion, you could perhaps look into getting a VPS? One of my friends (text book village (.) com) got a vps from computinghost.com , they compiled everything for him but the $10 control panel gives you Zpanel as your control panel.. So, if you can manage through command line or can do everything through your application's interface.. I would recommend it.

They also give shared hosting services, maybe contacting their support would help

Answer (score 0):

For Rails, it's better to have your own environment than a shared hosting like Dreamhost.

Heroku, will be the first recommendation, the current stack is Cedar Stack  which supports Ruby 1.9.3. Free if you are using only one Dyno (approx. 512MB RAM), 10K records in DB.

We also use DigitalOcean - http://digitalocean.com for some of our hosting. Plans start from $5 for 512 MB RAM. You can run a decent sized rails app on this.

You can also look at AWS, which provides one year free tier, basically hosting, storage etc - http://aws.amazon.com/free/ It's a good option if you think you need to scale in by end of the year.